# include asp from different domain in php page

Tags: php, asp.net

I have a work project that I am attempting to tackle.

I have a wamp server running on one machine with php installed, and a sql server running on the main server.

I have a basic asp script that when handed a variable via the url returns the required results out of the database. I have another pretty extensive site built on the wamp server which I want to embedd the output of the asp script into.

I can use an Iframe to display the results on the page, however because it is coming from a different domain, does not want to dynamically handle the height correctly and there isn't a constant height that I can program for.

I would like to use an include, but that doesn't seem to want to actually run the asp script when it brings in the file. This is what I want to do so that the results from the asp script become part of the page...

```
$centerContent .= include "http://192.168.168.199/portal/index.asp?orderNumber=".$_POST['orderNumber'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/file_get_contents):

```
$url = "http://192.168.168.199/portal/index.asp?orderNumber=".$_POST['orderNumber'];
$centerContent .= file_get_contents($url);
```

Comment: And that does it. Thanks very much Brock.